# Why does the Android SDK need a JDK?

Tags: android, compilation, java

I am trying to understand why the Android SDK needs the JDK.

- The Android SDK is not supposed to have all the JDK Java classes it needs (with potential implementation differences) ?
- Does it need it for all the tools included in the JDK ?
- Do we use the JDK when we build .dex & .apk files ?
- What does it mean to say that Android Java classes must be written with Java 5 or 6 compiler compliance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: ANdoBuild]

> The general process for a typical build is outlined below:
>
> - The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application    resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML
>   files for your Activities, and compiles them. An R.java is also
>   produced so you can reference your resources from your Java code.
> - The aidl tool converts any .aidl interfaces that you have into Java    interfaces.
> - All of your Java code, including the R.java and .aidl files, are    compiled by the **Java compiler** and .class files are output.
> - The dex tool converts the .class files to Dalvik byte code. Any 3rd    party libraries and .class files that you have included in your
>   project are also converted into .dex files so that they can be
>   packaged into the final .apk file.
> - All non-compiled resources (such as images), compiled resources, and    the .dex files are sent to the apkbuilder tool to be packaged
>   into an    .apk file.
> - Once the .apk is built, it must be signed with either a debug or    release key before it can be installed to a device.
> - Finally, if the application is being signed in release mode, you must    align the .apk with the zipalign tool. Aligning the final .apk
>   decreases memory usage when the application is running on a device.

[From here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html#detailed-build)

Comment: What about NDK?

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK uses the JDK to compile your `.java` files to `.class` bytecode.

Comment: So that means a .dex file is made from .class files ?

Comment: I'm quite sure Android SDK includes the "ecj.jar" or Eclipse Java Compiler jar, So I think that it wouldn't need separate java 5/6 compatible compiler.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project all .java files get converted to .class. For which you need JDK.

Now the dx tool of adk converts all .class files to classes.dex file .And this classes.dex file is executed on dalvik virtual machine.